# Why does magento generates random order id's

Tags: magento

One of my magento site shows zig-zag order numbers from admin panel sales->orders. I guess, it should be auto incremented. There is possiblity to skip few numbers due to uncompleted orders. But i get unusual number for an order. Last order id was 100001922 and i get order id for latest order 100001300. can anybody help me as i need to figure out the reason.

Comment: Does any extension(Random order number generator) installed ? Disable custom modules one by one it will lead you somewhere ahead positively.

Comment: No, we are not using any extension like random order no. generator.

Comment: As its a live site we can not disable any module. Also it does not happen with all orders. It happened for once and now order id is in sequence starting from 100001923. I just want to say that, its not known that when will i get a random order id again.